# Transform one row for columns where there is same data in other columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Long time have visited this site and got lot of help. Now I could not find what I'm looking for.
I'm working on Oracle SQL database

Table

```
columnA ColumnB ColumnC
 10A       AA      00
 10A       AA      10
 10A       AA      20
 10A       AA      30
 10A       BB      00
 10A       BB      10
 10A       BB      20
 10A       BB      30
```

and what I would like to do is extend the columns where there is same data in ColumnA and B like:

```
columnA ColumnB ColumnC ext.ColumnD ext.ColumnE ext.ColumnF
 10A       AA      00      10           20         30
 10A       BB      00      10           20         30
```

I have tried different pivots, tried lot of suggestions I've found forums but just cant get the result I hope for.

This is my first post so sorry in advance if there is something wrong or information is missing.

Thank you so much in advance!

/ edit

And there would not be same data in ColumnC always or even as many differents. If BB would not have 10 and have differents, it should look something like this:

```
columnA ColumnB ColumnC ext.ColumnD ext.ColumnE ext.ColumnF
 10A       AA      00      10           20         30
 10A       BB      00      17           47
```

Also goal is to get them increasing order, but that can be done with query, sorting in the first place.

---

/Edit

Now that I have this one table:

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC Height1 Height2 Height3 height4
5A        11       A       0       25       50     75
5A        11       B       0       25       50     75
5A        11       C       0       25       50  
5A        11       D       0       25       50     75
```

I have one row in the original table that have random digits which are unique and it needs to go after the height. pivot table with unique row:

```
ColumnA     ColumnB     ColumnC     Unique      ColumnE     ColumnF     ColumnG ColumnG
5A            11           A        16805097      00                            
5A            11           A        62366527                    25                      
5A            11           A        65672596                            75              
5A            11           A        68078617                                       50
```

So results would be:

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC Height1 Unique1 Height2 Unique2 Height3 Unique3 Height4 Unique4
5A       11      A       00     16805097  25    62366527  75    65672596  50   68078617
```

So if we would take the original question's table, the start point would be like this:

```
columnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD
 10A       AA      00    699787
 10A       AA      10    439567
 10A       AA      20    429456
 10A       AA      30    122172
 10A       BB      00    133244
 10A       BB      10    328311
 10A       BB      20    247422
 10A       BB      30    769636
```

Br
Jan

Comment: What if "BB" had no row with "10" in column C, what would the result look like?

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the original question with more details. -Jan

Comment: Using pivot it should be possible but only if you are ok with hard-coded values for pivoting clause?

Comment: What's your oracle version? It's important since PTF (Polymorphic table functions) are available only since Oracle 18

Comment: On earilier Oracle versions you can't write pure sql query that returns dynamic number of columns (Oracle CBO query parse limitations), so you will need something like my XT_PIVOT package based on Tom Kyte's Pivot package: https://github.com/xtender/XT_PIVOT

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Sujitmohanty30 pivot query worked like a charm. Br Jan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `PIVOT` as well and use it we can use `row_number()` to give a unique number by `partition columnA and columnB` and then use it in the pivoting clause.

The only disadvantage as you might be aware of is to hard code the values in the `PIVOT` clause. I have taken max 10 values as of now which you can adjust as per your need.

Note:- The column names generated by `PIVOT` will be in format of e.g. `COLUMND`,`COLUMNE` and so on.. which further can be changed at outer most query as you want. You can also give an alias to `MAX(columnC) some_alias` but then the columns names will be append it like `COLUMND_SOME_ALIAS`,`COLUMNE_SOME_ALIAS` and so on..

```
SELECT *
  FROM
(
SELECT columnA,columnB,columnC,
       row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY columnA,columnB ORDER BY columnC) rn_pivot
  FROM table1
)
PIVOT
(
 MAX(columnC)
 FOR rn_pivot IN (1 AS columnD
                 ,2 AS columnE
                 ,3 AS columnF
                 ,4 AS columnG
                 ,5 AS columnH
                 ,6 AS columnI
                 ,7 AS columnJ
                 ,8 AS columnK
                 ,9 AS columnL
                 ,10 AS columnM)
);
```

Comment: Oh dear exactly! This is working. Thank you Sujitmohanty30 so much! Appreciate!

Comment: @Jan00, nice. Would you mind accepting the answer if it has resolved your issue ? Thank you.:)

Comment: I just added more information. This was great, but forgot that I needed one more row to be shown in the results. Would you mind to look at the edit I made for original question? Thank you. After that this would be total package and done :) -Jan

Comment: @Jan00, normally in SO as I have seen, we need to post another question but your changes I believe is not big comparing to the original post. So what you do is just add `max(columnD)`. Like max(columnC),max(columnD) should work. I am not infront of my PC to validate it but it should work . Please check and give feedback otherwise I will check once I am with my laptop.

Comment: But the alias names you need to check how it's generating and if you need change there.

Comment: @Jan00, check this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9f5a473aefd27f5cccc6c61c2b7280a7

Comment: Thank you. I tried the first one and it gave 'column ambiguously defined', I try to fix that if possible. The second one, the link dbfiddle,  data in that are predefined? Or? Since the results can be anything, I like that pivot option. Ty

Comment: @Jan00, no no in the fiddle link just take the query from line 21 and below...the with clause is just to provide temporary data instead creating the table.

Comment: Oh no no, sorry. My bad. This actually work! Perfect! Thank you so much once again!  p.s how do you put @ in the first word to address comment to someone. In all my messages it just disappears

Comment: Yes right I too have noticed..just put some character like , or . after `@name,`

Answer (score 1):

If you combine the values in `ColumnC` into a single CSV list using `LISTAGG`, you can then use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to get the the values in that CSV list.  The example below returns up to 5 values for each combination of `ColumnA` and `ColumnB` but you can add additional `REGEXP_SUBSTR` columns if more than 5 are needed.

#### Query

```
WITH
    sample_data (cola, colb, colc)
    AS
        (SELECT '10A', 'AA', '00' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '10A', 'AA', '10' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '10A', 'AA', '20' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '10A', 'AA', '30' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '10A', 'BB', '00' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '10A', 'BB', '10' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '10A', 'BB', '20' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '10A', 'BB', '30' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '10A', 'BB', '40' FROM DUAL)
SELECT cola,
       colb,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR (colc_vals, '[^,]+', 1, 1) as colc_1,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR (colc_vals, '[^,]+', 1, 2) as colc_2,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR (colc_vals, '[^,]+', 1, 3) as colc_3,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR (colc_vals, '[^,]+', 1, 4) as colc_4,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR (colc_vals, '[^,]+', 1, 5) as colc_5
  FROM (  SELECT cola, colb, LISTAGG (colc, ',') within group (order by colc) AS colc_vals
            FROM sample_data
        GROUP BY cola, colb);
```

#### Result

```
   COLA    COLB    COLC_1    COLC_2    COLC_3    COLC_4    COLC_5
_______ _______ _________ _________ _________ _________ _________
10A     BB      00        10        20        30        40
10A     AA      00        10        20        30
```